# How to pass download image to another view controller

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm currently learning iOS development and was wondering how I would go about passing a downloaded image to another view controller to be displayed there after tapping on a cell. So, a user would tap on a cell that has an image and then another view controller would pop up with that image. I downloaded the image using URLSession and then cached the image so that the user wouldn't have download the image every time they scroll back up or down to another cell that they've already seen. My issue now is how would I get that downloaded image to another view controller? I tried this, but videoController.thumbnailImageView.image is still coming back as nil.

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let videoController = VideoController()
    let videoUrl = URL(string: Videos[indexPath.item].thumbnail_image_name)
    videoController.titleLabel.text = Videos[indexPath.item].title
    videoController.thumbnailImageView.image = self.imageCache.object(forKey: videoUrl as AnyObject) as? UIImage
    show(videoController, sender: Videos[indexPath.item])
}
```

Here is how I'm caching the images in cellForItemAt indexPath function.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)

    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For anyone wondering you have to do this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! VideoCell
    let videoController = VideoController()
    videoController.titleLabel.text = Videos[indexPath.item].title
    videoController.thumbnailImageView.image = cell.thumbnailImageView.image
    show(videoController, sender: self)
}
```

You need to create the cell for the cell item at that selected Index path. I'm not sure why the cached way didn't work, but when I found out I will update this question for anyone else wondering.